# Remove value from associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove specific element from a javascript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-a-javascript-array)

I am having an array, from which I want to remove a value.

Consider this as an array

`[ 'utils': [ 'util1', 'util2' ] ]`

Now I just want to remove `util2`. How can I do that, I tried using `delete` but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The surrounding square brace should be a bracket if this is an object literal.

Comment: I can't see an associative array.

Comment: var object = { 'utils': [ 'util1', 'util2' ] }

object.utils.splice(1, 1);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method:

```
var object = { 'utils': [ 'util1', 'util2' ] }

object.utils.splice(1, 1);
```

If you don't know the actual position of the array element, you'd need to iterate over the array and splice the element from there. Try the following method:

```
for (var i = object.utils.length; i--;) {
    var index = object.utils.indexOf('util2');

    if (index === -1) break;

    if (i === index) {
        object.utils.splice(i, 1); break;
    }
}
```

Update: techfoobar's answer seems to be more idiomatic than mine. Consider using his instead.

Comment: +1, you're nearly there: It's `object.utils.splice(1, 1)`. You have to tell it how many to remove (the second `1`). The first `1` just tells it at what index to do something. *Edit:* Yup, there you go. :-)

Comment: What if the object was defined like this: `var object = { 'utils': [ 'util2', 'util1' ] }`?

Comment: Darin wanted to say, what if the order of the elements is different. It's all answered in the question this one is a duplicate of.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. This solution will only work in some very particular case.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Then you would do `.utils.splice(0)`

Comment: What if you don't know the order? What I mean is that the usefulness of your solution is pretty limited. You assume way too many things about the order of elements in the array.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Good question. I think you'd have to loop.

Comment: Sure, could you update your answer to include this information and provide more useful solution?

Comment: @David - You do not need to loop through the utils array, and then do a `Array.indexOf()` inside it.

Comment: @techfoobar what is your alternative suggestion in this case?

Comment: @David - Unless there are multiple items in the array with the same value (that you need deleted), you can just do an `indexOf()` once and splice from the index it returns.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Array.splice()` in combo with `Array.indexOf()` to get the desired behavior without having to loop through the array:

```
var toDelete = object.utils.indexOf('util1');
if(toDelete != -1) {
    object.utils.splice(toDelete, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such thing called associative array in Javascript. It is actually an object.

```
[ 'utils': [ 'util1', 'util2' ] ]
```

For this line, I don't think it would compile. You should write this instead.

```
var obj = { 'utils': [ 'util1', 'util2' ] }
```

So to remove the element "util2" in the array (the inside array), there are 2 ways.

1. use pop()

   ```
   obj["utils"].pop(); // obj["utils"] is used to access the "property" of the object, not an element in associative array
   ```
2. reduce the length

   ```
   obj["utils"].length --;
   ```